# PHP/cURL file transfer limit over SSL?

Tags: php, iis, file-upload, curl, ssl

I have written a couple of PHP scripts using cURL to transfer files from ServerA to ServerB via an SSL connection. Both are Windows servers running IIS. The code works fine with smaller files (under about 7MB). However, it fails for anything larger than that.

It seems to be an issue with SSL. I temporarily opened up an http port on ServerB, and was able to send a 650MB file successfully. But when sending over SSL, it bombs. Using Wireshark, I can see that it sends about 7-8MB pretty quickly, then no more packets go out. The script just hangs until it times out.

The cURL error that I get back is: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054

Is there some sort of sending limitation on cURL SSL connections?

Comment: curl+ssl using what protocol? ftp? scp? sftp? error 10054 is "connection closed by peer".

Comment: I'm just opening up an https connection, and transferring the file via POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a full day and a half of trying everything, I found the solution. So simple. All I had to do was add:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
```

Hope this thread saves someone else from the agony I've been through trying to figure this one out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you update the default `post_max_size` in php.ini to something larger than the default which is 8MB:

```
post_max_size = 8M
```

Be sure to restart IIS afterwards. If this does fix it, I'm not sure why it would have worked for HTTP and not HTTPS, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah, I've maxed out every setting in php.ini and IIS that I can think of would have anything to do with this. All file size limits are set to a GB or more, and all timeouts are set to at least 60 minutes. The strange thing is that there is no consistency in the amount of data transferred, or the amount of time it runs.